# Spring boot geoserver File Editing

Tags: spring-boot, postman, put, geoserver, http-status-code-500

I have a problem with PutMapping to edit style from http://10.56.56.66:8081/geoserver/rest/styles by body in postman. When I enter http://localhost:8055/point where point is my style I get error 500. When You will enter http://10.56.56.66:8081/geoserver/rest/styles/point.sld you will download point.sld. And that's the file that I want to edit

```
package exp.tries;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Base64;

@RestController
public class StyleController {

private final WebClient webClient;

public StyleController(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
    this.webClient = webClientBuilder.baseUrl("http://10.56.56.66:8081/geoserver/rest/styles")
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, createBasicAuthHeader())
            .build();
}

private String createBasicAuthHeader() {
    String auth = "geoserver:geoserver";
    byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encode(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    return "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);
}

@GetMapping(value = "/{style}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Mono<String> getDefaultPointStyle(@PathVariable String style) {
    return webClient.get()
            .uri("/" + style + ".sld")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);
}

@PutMapping(value = "/{style}", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> updateStyle(@PathVariable String style, @RequestBody 
String newContent) {
    return webClient.put()
            .uri("/" +  style + ".sld", style)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(newContent))
            .retrieve()
            .toEntity(String.class)
            .map(response -> {
                if (response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                    return ResponseEntity.ok("Zawartość pliku SLD została zaktualizowana.");
                } else {
                    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Błąd 
podczas aktualizacji zawartości pliku SLD.");
                }
            })
            .onErrorReturn(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Błąd 
podczas wykonywania żądania PUT na serwerze GeoServer."));
}


@GetMapping("/edit-style/{stylere}")
public ClassPathResource getEditStylePage(@PathVariable String stylere) {
    return new ClassPathResource("/templates/edit_style.html");
}
}
```